# Removing CSS code from a theme using a custom theme

Tags: css, custom-theme, magento2.3.1

Im not sure this is possible but I wanted to ask.

I have a theme installed and it adds alot of CSS to the search input which breaks a custom module that also works with the search input.

I cant just overwrite the CSS using a custom.less file, i actually want to remove certain parts from the themes CSS file.  I can obviously delete lines of code from the themes own CSS files, but I was wondering if this can be done from a custom theme?

As an example, this code is in the themes CSS file;

```
.page-wrapper .page-header .header_right .block-search input {
    /* width: auto; */
    /* height: auto; */
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #5C5C5C;
    background-color: white;
    color: #5C5C5C;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Is there a way to delete this content (not overwrite it) from a custom theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that you can overwrite the entire CSS file like you would any other type of file in a custom theme i.e. app/design/frontend/customtheme/modulename/web/css/filename.less

Magento will then use the custom theme css/less file over the one in the module or child themes

i.e.

```
.page-wrapper .page-header .header_right .block-search input {

}
```

The above would remove all of the content from that CSS block when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this css into the theme and also run the following commands:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

And then please check the your css is deleted.

Comment: Erm thanks, but the answer in no way relates to the question!

Comment: Ok so what you want ? please more specify

Comment: I thought that I was clear in the question.  Please let me know which part you do not understand?  You have told me how to do an upgrade.  Unless upgrade schema were advanced to the next upgrade point all i would do is clear the cache and reindex over an existing good index and get an error deploying static content in developer mode